# Border Transition on <h1>< a> different timing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create this button esque thing that is a white h1 with an a link inside it that has a 5px white border and I want the entire thing to act as a link, including the border. I managed to get all the transitions right but due to the border and the actual link somehow being seperate when you mouseover just the border it does not affect the link text and clicking it doesn't take you anywhere.

Here's my code:

```css
body, html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

}

ul a {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 15px 25px;
 outline: none;
 color: #f5f5f5;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 26px;
  z-index:
}

ul a:hover,
ul a:focus {
 outline: none;
  z-index:
}


ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10%;
  width: 35%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18pt;
}


li a {
  outline: none;
 padding: 8px 0;
}

li a::after {
  outline: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 4px;
 background: #eb4f43;
 content: '';
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.3s;
 transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
 -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
 transform: translateY(10px);
}

li a:hover::after,
li a:focus::after {
  outline: none;
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
 -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
 transform: translateY(0px);
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 1.75%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

.i1, .i2, .i3 {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.i2 {
  background-color: #333;
}


#ptitle {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
}

#prole {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 28pt;
}

.plink a,
.plink {
 -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
 -moz-transition: color 0.2s;
 transition: color 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;  
}

.plink a:hover::before,
.plink a:focus::before {
 color: #f5f5f5;
}

.plink a:hover,
.plink a:focus,
.plink:hover,
.plink:focus {
 color: #eb4f43;
}

.plink:hover,
.plink:focus {
  border: 4px #eb4f43 solid;
}

.plink {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 46.1%;
  left: 15%;
  border: 4px #f5f5f5 solid;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-top: 0.8%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;

}
```

```html
<html> 
  <body>
    <div class="header">

      <ul>
        <li><a id="navlink" href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
        <li><a id="navlink" href="#">CLIENTS</a></li>
        <li><img class="logo" src="logo.png" href="logo.png"></li>
        <li><a id="navlink" href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a id="navlink" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="i1">
      <div>
        <h1 class="plink"><a href="#">LEARN MORE</a></h1>
        <h1 id="ptitle">PROJECT: MOVIES</h1>
        <h1 id="prole">UI/UX</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://thechangingperspectiveblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/MOUNTAINS-4-of-11.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the part where I think I messed up:

```
.plink a,
.plink {
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s;
    transition: color 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;  
}

.plink a:hover::before,
.plink a:focus::before {
    color: #f5f5f5;
}

.plink a:hover,
.plink a:focus,
.plink:hover,
.plink:focus {
    color: #eb4f43;
}

.plink:hover,
.plink:focus {
  border: 4px #eb4f43 solid;
}
```

And it's regarding the LEARN MORE "button"

Answer (score 0):

You should put all your styles on `.plink a` and avoid putting styles on `.plink`.

```css
h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 28pt;
}

.plink a {
 -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
 -moz-transition: color 0.2s;
 transition: color 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;  
  
  border: 4px #f5f5f5 solid;
}

.plink a:hover::before,
.plink a:focus::before {
 color: #f5f5f5;
}

.plink a:hover,
.plink a:focus {
 color: #eb4f43;
  
  border: 4px #eb4f43 solid;
}

.plink {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 46.1%;
  left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="plink"><a href="#">LEARN MORE</a></h1>
```